# Even/Odd every two posts

Tags: posts

I need to display a different layout every two posts, is it possible to achieve this by using even/odd?

```
<?php while (have_posts()): the_post() ?>
   <?php if ($wp_query->current_post % 2 == 0): ?>
      even
   <?php else: ?>
      odd
   <?php endif ?>
<?php endwhile ?>
```

Comment: Yes, it is. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: I am only able to have a different layout every other post, I need to use it every 2.

Comment: `$wp_query->current_post > 1 && $wp_query->current_post % 2 == 1` should do that, @Sullivan. I.e. The 3rd, 5th, 7th, and so on posts would be using the alternate layout.

Comment: Thanks Sally CJ but I actually need 1st & 2nd left-aligned then 3rd & 4th right-aligned and so on.

Comment: Have you looked at the `nth-child` selector in CSS?

Comment: Thanks birgire but I actually need to use a completely different layout, only used the left/right align as an example :)

Comment: @Sullivan ok, otherwise it would be e.g.  `div.box:nth-child(4n+1), div.box:nth-child(4n+2) { // ... change default layout for every 4n+1 and 4n+2. }` for multiple `div.box` items.

Answer (score 0):

Your code, while looking like it could be every other, is based on math, so it will be even and odds as the query goes by iterations counting up.  modulus 2 == 0 means even numbers in this sense (iteration / 2 has no remainder has to be an even number)

If you're looking to have every 2 posts together you could do this:

```
<?php 

while (have_posts()): the_post()
    $count = $wp_query->found_posts; //counts all items in query
    echo '<div>'; //starts first row
    echo '<div>'.$content.'</div>';
    if ($wp_query->current_post % 2 == 0) echo '</div><div>'; //ends row every other iteration
    if ($wp_query->current_post % 2 == $count )echo '</div>'; // ends final row
endwhile 
?>
```

`post_count` is the count of posts for that particular page, while `found_posts` is the count for all available posts that meets the requirements of the query without pagination.